# Which framework should I use to run OData APIs on Android?

Tags: android, frameworks, odata, restlet, odata4j

I am creating a program for Android mobiles which will query, retrieve and then process OData from an OData provider via a webservice.

Please can you tell me which toolkit is best for this? I have seen these:

- [odata4j](http://code.google.com/p/odata4j/)
- [restlet](http://restlet.com/downloads/current/)

Thanks.

Comment: A better place to ask this might be http://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: No, this is the right place (see http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/12/hello-stack-overflow.html). android.stackexchange.com seems to be for generic Android questions, there aren't many (any?) programming questions on there. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Restlet is very straightforward, although the performance is not the best. Check this article: [Accessing oData from Android using Restlet](http://weblogs.asp.net/uruit/archive/2011/09/13/accessing-odata-from-android-using-restlet.aspx).

[odata4j](http://odata4j.org) might be more performant according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858041/how-can-i-speed-up-restlet-for-android-when-using-odata/3955381#3955381) answer.

Answer (score 2):

Hey, I have been using restlet, it's extremely slow! I think it wouldn't be so difficult for you to write a parser yourself, there are many XML or JSON available nowadays. And consume an Odata service only needs a simple Apache Client!